# Публикация тестовой и рабочей версий приложения в Google Play Market

Tags: android, playmarket

Есть рабочая версия приложения для Android в Play Market.
Хочется изменения протестировать не затрагивая рабочую версию.
Можно одновременно иметь в Play Market и рабочую и закрытую версии?

Comment: это реализуется через бета-тестирование

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да вполне, этот раздел для этого и нужен. Позволяет тестировать не затрагивая рабочую версию. Потом можно перевести в рабочую версию или загрузить новую версию для тестирования.